# Android : Install different flavors with same package names

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I developed an android app with 3 different flavors (production,testing, training). Almost 99% of the source codes are identical. Only a single file in assert folder with server urls are different for each flavor. The flavors work perfectly. But i would like the app to install all 3 apps in the device without overwriting each other. Since the package name of the project is the same for all the flavors, it's overwriting the app when i install difference flavors.

Any ideas or suggestions ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't changing the package name for each flavor be a solution?

Comment: You should create a library project with the core logic and just include that in 3 separate projects with different package names. Android apps are identified by the package name so its needs to be unique for every app.

Comment: Actually all the source files are the same only the configuration file in the assert is different. So just wondering creating a different package names for each flavor is much to do. Is it possible to access the activities if packages names are different in the flavors ?

Comment: You mean a file in assets folder?

Comment: @joao2fast4u yup a file in assert folder. i changed the package names and now i can install all the 3 flavors in the device. Just wondering, is there a option to give different app names in build.gradle for flavors, or i have to copy the string.xml into the flavor folders ?

Answer (score 1):

Anyway just by changing the package name in the build.gradle it works.

```
productFlavors {
    production {
        applicationId = "<your-package-surfix>.production"
    }

    testing {
        applicationId = "<your-package-surfix>.testing"
    }

    training {
        applicationId = "<your-package-surfix>.training"
    }
}
```

In AndroidManifest.xml use full package name when define a activity/service/receiver.

Comment: with the new gradle 1.* update.. cant use testing as a flavour name.. its reserved for test...

Comment: not working with with error, packageName will not be changed in build variants. Error:(29, 0) Could not set unknown property 'packageName' for ProductFlavor_Decorated

Comment: @NaveedAhmad this is a old post.. You dont need packageName anymore. Gradle doesn't support the packageName property anymore. Just applicationId will do.